# Avoid Repetition

Tags: repetition-structure

I am in the process of writing a Japanese text.
It is meant to be a script for a presentation. 
Below, you find the draft version.

それぞれのモジュールに付属した単体試験が実施されました。

ところが、当時は、これらの試験を**求める工程はありませんでした**。

モジュールの要求から顧客ニーズへの後ろ向きの追跡を**求める工程もありませんでした**。

それどころか、これらの要求を書き留めるよう**求める工程もありませんでした**。

I am wondering whether there is an elegant way to avoid the repetition of "**求める工程もありませんでした**". Maybe, somebody has an idea.

Comment: I have difficulty making a valid interpretation of ～を求める工程 in this context. Could you elaborate you want to tell by this expression?

Answer (score 1):

> モジュールの要求から顧客ニーズへの逆方向の追跡**も**、それどころか、これらの要求を書き留めること**さえも**、求められていませんでした。
>
> モジュールの要求から顧客ニーズへの逆方向の追跡**も**、それどころか、これらの要求を書き留めること**さえも**、工程には存在しませんでした。

I would say like either of above.

> NPを求める工程もありませんでした。 (NP=Noun Phrase)
>
> There is no procedure which ask for NP.

Since the variable part in your lines are inside modifier clause, I think you need to make a verb so as to take NP as its subject.

> NPは求められていませんでした
>
> NP was not asked for.

or

> NPは工程に存在しませんでした
>
> NP was absent on any procedures.

Finally you can connect multiple NP with も, you can also use さえも for emphasizing like 'even'. 「NP1もNP2さえも求められていませんでした。」

By the way, we often use 後ろ向き as 'negative', so I suggest to use 逆方向 or 逆向き to mean the opposite direction.